# Html.ActionLink to maintain text format

Tags: jquery, css, text, format, html.actionlink

```
<div id="divtitle"> @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayTitle.TitleValue, "DisplayResults", "Results", new { filename = FileName }, new { @class = "resultsLink", TooltipData = item.DisplayTitle.Value })</div>
```

So my DisplayTitle is made up of two or three items, this could be: document title and document owner, a user can specify the length and order of the information,

```
document title ---> takes 60 characters

document owner ---->takes 20 characters
```

So my results are coming back as (note: the "_" are white spaces)

```
Document 1__________________________John

The Definitive C++ Book__________Stuart
```

and so on, is there a way in which I can maintain this format? and also the tooltip should maintain the format

Using the underscore has just made me think that maybe I can make them transparent, thus giving the illusion of spaces?

I hope that it makes sense what i am trying to achieve

Many thanks

Comment: I have tried using the underscores, and then make them transparent and it works. You can view it here:http://jsfiddle.net/galastur/uCjxq/2/

However, I am pretty sure that there has to be a cleaner solution, I don't like this idea